# Не работает клик по кнопке в скрипте JQUERY

Tags: jquery

```js
// btn "выбрать"
function showPackage(){
   var $this=$(this); 
    var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
    var $detailBox=$parent.find('.channel__menu')
}

function selectPackage(){
  var $this=$(this);  
  var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
  $('.package__container--selected').removeClass('package__container--selected');
  $(".package__main-btn").removeClass('package__main-btn--selected');
  $this.addClass('package__main-btn--selected');
  $parent.addClass('package__container--selected')
}

function ready(){
  $('.arrow-container').on('click',showPackage)
  $('.package__main-btn').on('click',selectPackage)
}  
$(document).ready(ready)

// изменение кнопки "добавить"
function showDetail(){
   var $this=$(this); 
    var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
    var $detailBox=$parent.find('.channel__menu')
}

function selectBox(){
  var $this=$(this);  
  var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
  $('.package__container--selected').removeClass('package__container--selected');
  $(".package__add-btn").removeClass('package__add-btn--selected');
  $this.addClass('package__add-btn--selected');
  $parent.addClass('package__container--selected')
}

function ready(){
  $('.arrow-container').on('click',showDetail)
  $('.package__add-btn').on('click',selectBox)
}  
$(document).ready(ready)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Кнопка "добавить" работает, а "выбрать" нет
https://codepen.io/st-iv/pen/BdrKxX

Comment: на кнопку выбрать события нет вообще $('.package__main-btn').on('click',selectPackage)

Comment: почему же? есть в функции function ready(){
  $('.arrow-container').on('click',showPackage)
  $('.package__main-btn').on('click',selectPackage)
}

Comment: проблема в том что для кнопки "добавить" работает аналогичный скрипт, но как только я уберу скрипт для кнопки "добавить", начинает работать кнопка "выбрать"

Answer (score 0):

Слишкоом долго, решил сам

```js
// btn "выбрать"
function showPackage(){
   var $this=$(this); 
    var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
    var $detailBox=$parent.find('.channel__menu')
}

function selectPackage(){
 
  var $this=$(this);  
  var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
  $('.package__container--selected').removeClass('package__container--selected');
  $(".package__main-btn").removeClass('package__main-btn--selected');
  $this.addClass('package__main-btn--selected');
  $parent.addClass('package__container--selected')
}

// изменение кнопки "добавить"
function showDetail(){
   var $this=$(this); 
    var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
    var $detailBox=$parent.find('.channel__menu')
}

function selectBox(){
  
  var $this=$(this);  
  var $parent=$this.closest('.container');
  $('.package__container--selected').removeClass('package__container--selected');
  $(".package__add-btn").removeClass('package__add-btn--selected');
  $this.addClass('package__add-btn--selected');
  $parent.addClass('package__container--selected')
}

function ready(){
  $('.arrow-container').on('click',showDetail);
  $('.package__add-btn').on('click',selectBox);
  $('.arrow-container').on('click',showPackage);
  $('.package__main-btn').on('click',selectPackage);
}  
$(document).ready(ready)
```